# what are valid register variable types

Tags: c++, cpu-registers

I want to know the variable types that are valid with register keyword for fast access. For example can I have

```
register int i;
register char ch;
register float f;
```

I would also like to know how many register variables can I declare in my program.

Comment: This depends on the compiler and architecture. There is no "general case" answer. Some compilers completely ignore the `register` keyword, even without any optimizations turned on.

Comment: This question would only make sense in context of a specific implementation.\

Comment: The register storage specifier originally applies only to variables of type int, char, or pointer types.

Comment: I think modern compilers are very smart so they implicitly optimizes frequently used variables for speed (fast access) & puts them in CPU register.
So optimisers are so good at register allocation nowadays that any attempt from the programmer to enforce their will through the register keyword would likely lead to a pessimisatin, and is therefore simply ignored by the compiler.SIMPLY PUT:register keyword are not used nowadays.

Comment: To augment @GovindParmar comment, different CPUs (processors) have different quantities of registers.  From that perspective, you would have to research your processor to find out how many registers it has.  Next, compilers are in charge of allocating registers.  This reduces the number of available registers (for example, one register my be a pointer to a stack, another to hold the return address).  Also, depends on the variable usage (scope) within a program.  In summary, write your code so that the compiler can easily allocate variables.

Comment: The data types that can be supported by a register depend on the capacity of a register.  An 8-bit register cannot hold an `int` type, since the range of an `int` exceeds 8 bits.  Common data types for registers:  `uint8_t, uint16_t, uint32_t, char, unsigned char, signed char, int, unsigned int, float, double and pointer`.  Your Mileage May Vary.

Comment: I have found that the compiler may ignore your suggestions for register allocation depending on the optimization setting.

Comment: Also, restricting the scope of a variable and declaring variables as `const` and closest to usage will enable the compiler to better use the registers.

Answer (score 5):

[The `register` keyword](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/register) was deprecated in C++11, and because *unused and reserved* in C++17.

**You shouldn't use it** and I would also be surprised if it actually meant anything significant to modern compilers.

Answer (score 2):

**Note**: [register](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration) keyword is deprecated until C++17,  unused and reserved since C++17.

**To talk in  general**

The register storage specifier originally applies only to variables of type int, char, or pointer types. However, it applies to any type of variable. In practice, the register has significant effect on integer and character variables only. Also keep in mind that the register specifier is applied to local variables and formal parameters to a function(Global register variables are not allowed).

Actually you don't need to worry about declaring many register variables. In case of too many register variables, the compiler automatically transforms them into non register variables (if limit is reached). At least two register variables of type int or char can be actually held in the CPU register.

Comment: The first sentence of the answer tells only half of the story, and could easily be (mis?)interpreted such that `register` could be used from C++17 onwards. I could not find a mention in the standard that register has significant effect on only integer and character types What is your source for that claim? (off topic: the classification is a bit redundant, since character types are integers).

Comment: @user2079303 source is `The Complete reference Fourth Edition` by  `Herbert Schildt` page 32 under `register Variables` last para http://home.iitj.ac.in/~ug201310035/H.Schildt.Cpp.The.Complete.Reference.4th.Edition.ENG.pdf